# Can't find header field in my pdfs generated from read-the-docs

Tags: read-the-docs

I have tried but I can't find the answer anywhere, so here goes.

In the pdfs I generate for my read-the-docs website the header seems to have a missing field. On the top-right of the header I see:

, Release foobar

I would like to either:

- add some text before the comma
- remove the comma itself

I understand that the header is generated in the conf.py file and the fix needs to go there:

```
# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'Documentation'
copyright = '2021, Companyname'
author = 'Me'
release = 'foobar'
```

What variable can I add here? Any help welcome.

Jim.

Comment: Link to the project?

Comment: The project is company internal, so I can't I'm afraid...